# Transform voltage/amperage ratio in DC current

Tags: transformer, dc

Transformers can be used with AC  to reduce voltage and increase current.

Is there a way to do the same with DC?

In an extreme case, theoretically speaking, let’s say I have a power source that gives 400 V / 1 mA DC, how could I transform the ratio to 200 V / 2 mA DC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capacitors and inductors are components that store energy, by passing current through them (inductors store energy in the form of a magnetic field, capacitors use an electric field), and that stored energy can be recovered at a later time. They both have time-dependent behaviour, requiring and developing currents and voltages that change over time.

In contrast to capacitors and inductors, any resistive element in the path of flow of current (either in or out, or at any point in between) in a system will create heat, a form of energy which is next to impossible to recuperate, and is essentially lost.

Remembering the power equation \$P=I\times V\$, your question is about efficiency:

$$ P_{IN}=400V \times 1mA\ = 0.4W $$

and

$$ P_{OUT}=200V \times 2mA\ = 0.4W $$

which is the same as saying power out equals power in, or the system is 100% efficient. In other words, whatever system you use to convert between those two conditions must contain *no finite resistive element* that could lose any of those Joules of energy to heat.

Also, that requirement for changing currents and voltages means that we must still employ some kind of changing of state, but we can be clever about it. If we can make those changes very small, fast and frequent, so that on average we see "steady" voltage conditions, we can call it DC.

There are dozens of configurations of switches, inductors and capacitors that  can perform the function of getting more or less volts or amps out than in, with (close to) 100% efficiency, but I'll illustrate only one here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEczum.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this setup we use switch SW1 to close the loop consisting of V1, L1 and SW1, causing a current to build up in that loop. That's not instant, because of L1, which is building up a magnetic field, and slowing the rise of current.

The nature of the inductor is to oppose change in current. Therefore, when SW1 opens again, current doesn't just stop flowing, it continues to flow via the only path available to it, D1. All the energy of the inductor's magnetic field is now "dumped" into capacitor C1, as a result of current being pushed through C1, and the energy is now stored in C1, which is manifest as a voltage across C1.

Each closing and opening of SW1 causes a "packet" of energy to be transferred from the voltage source V1 to C1, each time increasing the voltage across C1 a little bit.

With careful control of the rate of switching of SW1, and the duration of each closure, we have very precise control of the voltage accumulated on C1. When we reach the required voltage, we stop switching. If some load at OUT draws current from C1, causing its voltage to drop too low, we start switching again, topping up C1. As long as we don't remove energy from the capacitor quicker than we can top it up, we can very precisely control the *average* voltage across C1.

If the transfers of packets of energy are 100% efficient (we use an ideal inductor, an ideal capacitor, and a switch with zero on-resistance) no heat is generated, and the whole process is 100% efficient.

You can have 400V in, and 200V out, at 100% efficiency. However, there may be a very small amount of "ripple" at the output, due to the capacitor being topped up with each packet transfer. If we keep the frequency of switching high enough, and the "packets" of energy small enough, the ripple is small, and we can call the output DC.

Of course, it's up the the load at the output to determine the current drawn from this 200V supply, but you get the idea. Due to 100% efficiency, if you drew 2mA from node OUT, you would measure only 1mA flowing out of source V1.

In practice, SW1 is implemented using some kind of transistor.

Comment: I *think* there is an error in the topology of your circuit, with L1 and D1 being in series like that?

Comment: @DanielChisholm You are right. I thought about a more practical buck arrangement, but in this one it's really easy to see the concept of current being diverted through the diode after the path via the switch is blocked. I know it's more of a boost setup, but I also wanted to stay with OP's 400V in and 200V out. I should probably fix it.

Comment: Thanks ! Just to make sure : Am i right to say that the node OUT will take voltage from the capacitor AND current from the inductor as well ?

Comment: @Charles-UgoBrouillard the load will take current from whichever source has current to provide. Just like water being drawn from two sources, one source may provide more than the other one minute, and less the next, and it all depends on the flow impedances and relative pressures (potentials) at any instant.

Comment: It makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *switching power supply*. One can be designed such that the input and output are fixed by a ratio to give a "DC transformer", but generally, when you're going to the trouble of making one, you make the input or output regulated, at essentially no added cost.

Comment: (Mention DC/DC converter?)